# Intellij - scala class with companion object shows as object file?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

In Intellij, declaring companion object before its companion class displays `Scala Object File` instead of `Scala Class File` (that is, in left navigator pane, it shows `O` (object file) instead of `C` (class file)).

I kind of assumed that Intellij would pick up automatically the companion object and defaults to scala class file but it doesn't. However, it works just fine if I declare companion object after companion class.

Is there a setting in Intellij to rectify this?

Or should I change my coding style to accommodate this? (i.e Is it considered a good style to place companion object after class declaration in scala? I've been so far used to declaring `static fields` before `instance fields`)